# How to copy the dependency file of a dll during the build operation?

Tags: .net, dll, rdlc

We have created a library project for creating assigning report source for rdlcs. We also maintain rdlc files inside the library project. 
Now we are using this library project in multiple project by adding this project as reference.

While doing the build of projects the library project becomes as dll but we also need the rdlc files copied automatically to the build project.

is there any possibilities? please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use build events, there are pre-build and post-build events which are commonly used to copy files to a given place.  In solution explorer, select the project, properties and select build events.  There are a number of macros such as ProjectDir to help.